# 3 Horses out of 25 Horses

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

You've got 25 horses and you can host races in groups of 5. You don't have a stopwatch, obviously. Then what should be the minimum number of races that you should be conducting so as to ascertain the fastest 3 horses.